# How to assign base path using global variable in luman laravel?

Tags: php, web-services, laravel, global-variables

Am new one in luman laravel.How to assign base path using global variable in luman laravel?Suggestions welcome.

Comment: You can use `base_path()` method to get one...

Comment: Hi thanks .I need further more help in this case.Actually i assigned path root (example)in env file `FRONT_PATH=api/v1/borrower` and how to call the env function  in routes.php. now currently called like using env function with global variable in routes.php file `$app>get('env("FRONT_PATH")/test1','stateControllers@state');` .I dont know  this is correct way or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the URL facade which lets you do calls to the URL generator

So you can do:

```
URL::to('/');
```

You can also use the application container:

```
$app->make('url')->to('/');
$app['url']->to('/');
App::make('url')->to('/');
```

but in case of Laravel 5.2 you will have to use **url('/')**